# Linking together multiple classes?

Tags: java, class, minecraft

I have seen this question before but I'm not quite understanding what all of the intense Java Jargin means. I just want to know if its possible to have, for example an "A" and a "B" class

In my "A" Class it has all the main code that will get run within my game, but in the "B" class it will have all my variables defined and what each item is worth"

E.G

```
if(args [ 0 ].equalsIgnoreCase("sell") && args [ 1 ] !=(null)){
    int numOfItems = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    if(numOfItems == player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount()){
        player.getInventory().setItemInHand(null);
        getServer().dispatchCommand(getServer().getConsoleSender(), "eco give " + player.getName() + " " + Diamond);
    }else if(numOfItems > player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount()){
        player.sendMessage("not enough");
    }else if(numOfItems < player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount()){
        player.getInventory().getItemInHand().setAmount(player.getInventory().getItemInHand().getAmount() - numOfItems);
        getServer().dispatchCommand(getServer().getConsoleSender(), "eco give " + player.getName() + " " + Diamond);
    }
}
```

That is for a Minecraft plugin, and I want the variable "Diamond" to be able to Search its value in the "B" Class and then it will send the amount of money that Diamond is defined as to the player in the game.

Comment: Assuming `args` comes from the main method, `args[1]` can never be null. Either you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or there will be a `String`.

Comment: When you do things like `Integer.parseInt()`, you are using another class' method to do some work for you. Do the same thing for your classes A and B.

Comment: The Plugin works completely fine. no errors. I just want to define all of my variables in a different class. EDIT: Works, Just needed to change my variable to static and do B.diamond Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. All you need to do is declare an instance of 'B' in your main plugin class:

```
class B {
    Material diamond = Material.DIAMOND;
    //...other stuff
}

class Main {
//...

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
        if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("sell")) {
            B b = new B();
            //...
            //use b.diamond where appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the brevity; I was in such a hurry to write this. If you need further assistance, just let me know.